# Core Data: trigger a long-running operation on change of an attribute

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have in my model an object, that when modified requires a large number of other objects to recompute values based on those changes.

The way this is currently set up, is that this one object can only be modified in one place. This is a sheet with a Cancel and an OK button. Once the user commits the change, the sheet shows a progress bar and starts processing the objects affected by the change. The presentation and dismissal of the sheet are wrapped in a NSUndoManager group. The user may undo all changes in one pass after dismissing the sheet.

What bothers me is that I keep thinking that all this should happen at the business level. Rather than at the controller level. I.e. I should be able to modify my business object any place in the UI and code and have it trigger the necessary computations.

So I would set up KVO to watch my object and trigger the long running operation when needed. Once I go down that path, I start hitting walls.

- How do I coalesce changes? My object has several attributes. I don't want to start a computation when the first attribute is changed and the second is likely to change next. Basically I need an edit sheet and some control point to commit all changes at once.
- How do I add a UI to this long running operation? I could have an NSOperationQueue attached to the NSManagedObjectContext and have my window controller observe that. When the queue is not empty, I would pop up a sheet with a progress bar monitoring the current operation.
- How can I implement Undo/Redo support? If I delay recomputation to an operation running after the fact, I cannot imagine how to undo the initial change and the propagated once at the same time. I can only imagine undoing the original change and having that trigger another reevaluation of all other object.

In short:

What is the best practice for such dependancies?

Is the propagation a job for the model layer or the control layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I came up with a solution:

- the center-piece model object watches itself for changes
- on change, it creates or amends a ToDo object
- the controller watches for new ToDo objects
- the controller dequeues the ToDo, presents a progress-bar and performs the operation